# Cant import run from subprocess in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm trying to import the "run" module in subprocess.

```
from subprocess import run
```

Is this only for python 3.5?
I'm trying on python 3.4 and it says it cant import.

Comment: yes, it has been added only in 3.5. Use `call` in 3.4

Comment: [Note that it says new in 3.5 at bottom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: Here are the subprocess docs for 3.4 https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. From the Python documentation[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> The run() function was added in Python 3.5; if you need to retain
>   compatibility with older versions, see the Older high-level API[2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#call-function-trio)
>   section.